# Scroll to section jQuery Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I constantly get `Uncaught ReferenceError: sectionScrollTimer is not defined` in console when i turn the mouse wheel down. The code should scroll from div to div automatically when user turns the mouse wheel. What could be the problem?

```
  if ( jQuery('.dsd_section_to_scroll').length > 0 ) {

    jQuery('.dsd_section_to_scroll').first().addClass('active');

    jQuery(document).on('wheel', function (e) {
      if (jQuery(window).width() > 767) {
        var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        var scrollSections = jQuery('.dsd_section_to_scroll');
        var indexToScroll = -1;
        jQuery.each(scrollSections, function(index, item){
            if (jQuery(item).hasClass('active')){
              indexToScroll = index - delta;
            }
        });
        if (indexToScroll in scrollSections) {
            e.preventDefault();
            clearTimeout(sectionScrollTimer);
            sectionScrollTimer = setTimeout( function(){
                var next = jQuery(scrollSections[indexToScroll]);
                jQuery('body, html').animate({
                    scrollTop: next.offset().top
                }, 'slow');

                jQuery('.dsd_section_to_scroll').removeClass('active');
                next.addClass('active');
            }, 250 );
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Are u using a plugin ? `sectionScrollTimer = `must be a var declared at some global point.

Comment: No. I took the code from here http://philips.thedemourl.com/wp-content/themes/philipsmobile-child/js/dsd_scripts.js and it doesnt use any plugin

Comment: the first lines definde the global vars did you include that ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

```
var sectionScrollTimer = 0;
```

at the beginning.